# Product of all elements in a group

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

I'm reading Aluffi's "Algebra: Chapter 0", and have some difficulties with exercise II.1.8:

Let *G* be a finite group with exactly one element *f* with order 2. Prove that $П_{g\in G}(g)=f$

I've proved it for abelian groups, is it really true for all groups?

Comment: @MoisheKohan thx I've been trying to find it here for hours

Comment: Just look at the list of questions under the header "related" on the right-hand side of the page with your question. I was sure, I saw this question before and, sure enough, it was listed. Most duplicates can be found this way.

Comment: @MoisheKohan thx it works, didn't know about it

Answer (score 4):

There is a very neat but deep result here that goes a step further.

Let $G$ be a finite group of order $n$, say $G=\{g_1, g_2, ..., g_{n-1}, g_n\}$ and define $\wp(G)=\{g_{\sigma(1)} \cdot g_{\sigma(2)} \cdot \cdot \cdot g_{\sigma(n-1)}\cdot g_{\sigma(n)}: g_i \in G, i=1,... ,n$ and $\sigma \in S_n\}$, in other words $\wp(G)$ is the set of all possible products of $n$ different elements of $G$. (Of course the result of such product depends on the order of the elements, $G$ does not have to be abelian here!). Let $S$ be a Sylow $2$-subgroup of $G$.

If $S$ is non-cyclic or $\{1\}$ (that is $|G|$ is odd), then $\wp(G)=G'$.

If $S$ is cyclic, then $\wp(G)=xG'$, where $x$ is the unique element of order $2$ of $S$.

Comment: it's very interesting, but I don't understand what $G'$ means. If it s the commutator, is it trivial in our case?

Comment: It is the *commutator* subgroup of $G$, so $G'=\langle [x,y]: x,y \in G \rangle$. Note that $G'$ is the *smallest* normal subgroup of $G$ such that the quotient is abelian.